# How to authenticate Angular form for access to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can my Angular website backend get access to Realtime database? Do I need to assign my website itself an email and password? Is there some sort of token required? How do I authenticate the website rather than a user?

Currently my rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It seems that anyone could post to the database that way. I only want the website itself to be able to post. I want something like the rules below.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I understand how a user can be authenticated with email and password or google etc. How does the website itself get authenticated?

Comment: `website itself get authenticated?` can explain it more ? Basically firebase projects secret api keys are generated for you when you create new project in firebase. then you gives this api to your web-site using angular using firebase.initializeapp() method.

Comment: I have all the api keys installed. My question seems so simple. How does the backend of the website get past the Firebase rules without a blanket :true rule? A user is authenticated so that they can get past the rules to read or write. How is this done for the site itself so that forms can write?